# How to handle excessive log entries during transition to a new Kibana server?

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch

I am encountering a challenge while updating our Elasticsearch/Kibana setup, which involves two separate virtual machines named `Kibana01` and `Kibana02`. Each virtual machine hosts an instance of Ubuntu and the ELK stack. We are transitioning from an older setup on `Kibana01` to a newer setup on `Kibana02`, aiming to utilize the latest features and improvements of the ELK stack. Here are the specifics of each setup:

`Kibana01` VM:

- **Operating System**: Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS
- **ELK Stack**: Elasticsearch 7.5.2, with corresponding versions of Logstash and Kibana.

`Kibana02` VM:

- **Operating System**: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS
- **ELK Stack**: Elasticsearch 7.17.10, with corresponding versions of Logstash and Kibana.

##### Identified Problem:

We are seeing an abnormally high volume of log entries for the service `pim_queue_manager.sh` on the new Kibana server (`Kibana02`) compared to the old one (`Kibana01`). Here are the results obtained after running the following command on both servers:

```
administrator@par-kibana:~$ time gunzip -c syslog_facilities.txt | sort | uniq -c | sort -n
```

Kibana01 (Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS, Elasticsearch 7.5.2):

[image: numberfacilities_Kibana01]

Kibana02 (Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS, Elasticsearch 7.17.10):

[image: numberfacilities_kibana02]

The comparison revealed:
Kibana01 VM logs for pim_queue_manager.sh: 465,589 entries
Kibana02 VM logs for pim_queue_manager.sh: 32,786,602 entries

On `Kibana02`, the `pim_queue_manager.sh` service records 32,786,602 entries, compared to only 465,589 on `Kibana01`. This overload causes the `/var/log/syslog` directory to fill up too quickly, exceeding the management capabilities of logrotate and blocking the recording of new logs.

##### Hypotheses:

- **Process Loop**: A loop in a process on `Kibana02` could be responsible for this log overload.
- **Complete Transmission of Log History**: During the switchover, it appears that the virtual machines are sending their entire log history to `Kibana02`, treating it as if it were new. Normally, only post-switchover logs should be transmitted.

##### Request for Assistance:

I am seeking advice on how to solve these problems. How can I prevent the transmission of the complete log history to the new Kibana server and ensure a transition without overloading the log system?

Comment: Please edit your question: What are the exact versions (new and old) of Ubuntu, Elasticsearch and Kibana at play here? Without knowing the versions what does “new” versus “old” mean? Please edit your question to add these details.